# Fluentd - S3 output plugin - Impossible to use environment variable as part of S3 path

Tags: variables, amazon-s3, logging, kubernetes-helm, fluentd

Here is my use case:
We have hundreds of kubernetes pods that generate logs and send them to S3. For performance issues with the current solution, we are trying to implement fluentd as sidecars to those pods. Fluentd will send the logs to S3 in a format that includes some variables.

Here is the problematic line from the helm chart (in the `match` section):

`path logs/label/{{ $logName }}/env/dt=%Y-%m-%d/hr=%H/host="#{ENV['POD_NAME']}"/`

This line almost works as expected, except the last part with the pod name, even though the variable POD_NAME is defined in the container.

The s3 output creates a folder called host="#{ENV['POD_NAME']}" rather than use the environment variable.

Any help is welcome.
Thank you.

Comment: Try: `path "#{ 'logs/label/{{ $logName }}/env/dt=%Y-%m-%d/hr=%H/host=' + ENV['POD_NAME'] + '/' }"`

Comment: Thanks @Azeem. It worked as expected.

Comment: You're welcome! Good to hear that. I'll post that as an asnwer.

Answer (score 0):

To enable the embedded code evaluation, you need to enclose the value in the double quotes.

Syntax:

```rb
parameter "#{ <embedded-code-here> }"
```

So, your required configuration could be:

```rb
path "logs/label/{{ $logName }}/env/dt=%Y-%m-%d/hr=%H/host=#{ENV['POD_NAME']}/"
```

or, this, using string concatenation:

```rb
path "#{ 'logs/label/{{ $logName }}/env/dt=%Y-%m-%d/hr=%H/host=' + ENV['POD_NAME'] + '/' }"
```

For more on this, see:
https://docs.fluentd.org/configuration/config-file#embedded-ruby-code